# Mamp or Lamp apache redirect outgoing emails testing force address

Tags: apache, email, mamp, lamp, staging

Is there any way to redirect all outgoing emails of my local testing environment on Lamp or Mamp to send the emails to me overwritting what the PHP code says. So that it captures everything from the configuration level and sends them to me so that nothing slips out.

Thanks in advance.